# jquery: if ul has li with certain classname?

Tags: jquery, list

i wonder how i can query if a ul has a first-child li with a certain classname?

like…

```
<ul>
<li>list element 1</li>
<li>list element 2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li class="whatever">list element 1</li>
<li>list element 2</li>
</ul>
```

i want to query if ul has a child with classname whatever -> do something!
is that even possible?

thank you

Answer (score 5):

Combine the [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [`>` (immediate child)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selectors, like this:

```
$('ul:has( > li.whatever)')​
```

[You can view a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ck4b2/), this matches only if an **immediate** child `<li>` has `class="whatever"`, without the `>`, it would match if any descendant had that class.

Alternatively, go the other way:

```
$("li.whatever").parent("ul")
```

This would find all the immediate [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) of elements with that class only if they're a `<ul>` (as opposed to a `<ol>`).

---

I *think* you meant an *immediate* child, but in case you need to match only when the first `<li>` that's an immediate child has the class, add the [`:first-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/), like this:

```
$('ul:has( > li.whatever:first-child)')
```

[You can see a test page here](http://jsfiddle.net/ck4b2/6/)

Comment: You still need to add `:first` or `:first-child` (I think): *if a ul has a **first-child** li with a certain classname*

Comment: @Felix Kling: I *think* he means immediate child, which is often the case with `<ul>`/`<li>`, but I'll update in case that's the situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul').find('.whatever').length > 0
```

if so you have some, not else

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't get it wrong:

```
$(function(){
    $("ul li.whatever:first-child").css({border: "1px solid red"});
});
```